# update map marker position onLocationChanged() is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on google maps and I want to change map marker position when user location changed in `onLocationChanged()` method. I tried many solutions available on Stack overflow but none fits for me. 
I,ve tried [Update marker position on google map smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332968/update-marker-position-on-google-map-smoothly?rq=1) and many others but failed.

I didn't find a proper way of code to update marker.

Thanks a lot!

> here's my MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, TaskLoadedCallback {

    static Marker now;
    public static GoogleMap mMap;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_order);
        Log.i("map", "create");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment1 != null) {
            mapFragment1.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        initViews();
        setToolbar()
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

 mMap = googleMap;
        if (!runtime_permissions()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), serviceIntent);
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
            }
        }


        mMap.addMarker(place1);
        mMap.addMarker(place2);

        CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(31.527653,74.455632))
                .zoom(7)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 5000, null);

}
```

> here's my Service class

```
public class MyService  extends Service {


    public static LocationListener listener;
    public static LocationManager locationManager;
    private String locationAddress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                String userAddress = address(latitude, longitude);

                 /*not working*/
                Marker myMarker = null;
                if(myMarker == null){
                  //  marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                }
                else {
                    marker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        };

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //noinspection MissingPermission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, CommonObjects.DELAY_LOCATION_UPDATE, 0, listener);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note, mentioning how long you've been stuck on a problem is [considered rude here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). Also, what results are you getting now; odd behavior, error messages, crash, freeze or something else?

Comment: Move the declaration of the `myMarker` to a class field member scope.  Currently, it comes into scope on every location change and therefore is always set to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thinking I came to know that I can't update map marker in `onLocationChanged()`. Instead, I've to update my marker `onMapReady()` method.

By sending broadcast form my `Service` class to `onMapReady()` method, I got solution of the problem **update map marker position onLocationChanged()**

*Updated code:*

> MyService.java

```
public class MyService  extends Service {

     ...   

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

      ...
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                String userAddress = address(latitude, longitude);

                 /*sending broadcast*/
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
                i.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                i.putExtra("address", userAddress);
                sendBroadcast(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                ...
            }

        };

      ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

> MapsActivity.java

Also, here I'm starting `Service` in `onCreate()` rather than `onMapReady()`.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, TaskLoadedCallback {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_order);

       ...

       /* staring service from here*/
       if (!runtime_permissions()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), serviceIntent);
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(destination).title("Isl");
        mMap.addMarker(place2);

        /*receiving broadcast*/
        if (broadcastReceiver == null) {
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    lat = (double) intent.getExtras().get("latitude");
                    lng = (double) intent.getExtras().get("longitude");
                    String  userAddress = (String) intent.getExtras().get("address");

                    place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("Lahore");
                    mMap.addMarker(place1);
                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));


        CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(31.527653,74.455632))
                .zoom(7)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 5000, null);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add in locationChangedMethod

```
 MarkerOptions pin_01_markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    pin_01_markerOptions.position(currentLatLng);
                    pin_01_markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pin_01_marker));

                mMap.addMarker(pin_01_markerOptions);




 LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
                        15);
                mMap.moveCamera(update);
```

Comment: Exception ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference```
at ```mMap.addMarker(pin_01_markerOptions);```

Comment: because your googlmeMap is null.
in onMapReady method  intialize google map then after this code work

like 

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//mMap is global variable
        mMap=googleMap;

Comment: I tried with that too but still same error. Also, I edited my question according to your suggestion but still didn't work for me.

Comment: Please check on MapReady , google map is intializing or not
i think you have define in  fragment so check below code with your code
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);